# Is it possible to make a font to only work in the browser?

Tags: web, browser, fonts, opentype

I'm using a font from [TypeKit](https://typekit.com/) on a website. The website's design is made in Photoshop and I'd very much like to have the font available while designing. But TypeKit only allows you to embed the fonts on a website and doesn't provide any downloadable files.

However, I can of course just open the Web Inspector, go to Network and download the font (it's a "base64 URL", so I can't just download the file from a server). But for some reason I can't install the font. I get some kind of (parsing?) error in OS X. I have also tried several converters from OTF to TTF/WOFF with similar results. If I serve the downloaded font to a web browser it works, though.

So, is it possible to make a font (OTF in this case) to only work in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the base64 encoded string isn't in OTF format, as the MIME type suggests, but in WOFF format. So after converting the downloaded file from WOFF to TTF/OTF it can be installed.

Answer (score 0):

They are describing how they protect their fonts on their page: http://blog.typekit.com/2009/07/21/serving-and-protecting-fonts-on-the-web/

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm on the last step then, "Segmenting and subsetting". I don't really understand it, though. I mean, it's really only one base64 encoded string. If I decode it and serve it to a browser as a binary, it works. But if I try to install it, it doesn't work. I suspect it has something to do with the meta data instead. Maybe the title is missing, which works perfectly fine in a browser, but makes the OS to freak out.